# Issues with win key and right alt key after Windows Update (Polish diacritical signs not working)

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-layout, diacritics

I've got a problem that occured to me out of nowhere.

Today in the morning, as I logged in to my computer at work I cannot input Polish diacritical signs. For example <kbd>rAlt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> should give `Ą` but instead it gives no character. On the other hand : <kbd>rAlt</kbd> + <kbd>rCrtl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> gives the expected `Ą` sign. Also another weird thing: before the <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut opened the Run command without any lag or nothing. Today it opens the menu at first, after that proceeds to Run command.

I've checked every possible language setting. Everything is fine. Keyboard layout - Polish (Programmer) also is fine. Checked my graphics driver (since they can have some issues with shortcuts) and nothing. The OS is malware free. Any possible issue with shortcuts checked with no result.

My computer:
Samsung NP550P7C, Windows 8.1 Enterprise (after every possible update).

I hope there is another way than reinstalling the OS since I have alot of software to be reinstalled with it to enable me to work.

Comment: Have you installed or updated any software recently?

Comment: Do you have any Remote Desktop sessions open in the background? If yes, switch to any of these sessions and back and check if now you are able to type diacritical characters normally.

Comment: @gronostaj : no. yesterday I've downloaded VNC Viewer but without any installation. I've did a massive amount of updates today but it was after I've noticed the issue.

I need to state this that I've rebooted my system countless times today... with success sadly.

Comment: @MBu : I do not have any Remote connections active at the time but... Is it possible that some connections could have been terminated in a wrong way so the problem persists even without a connection ?

Comment: @PiotrTruszkowski: No, terminated RDP connections should not affect you in any way and you have already rebooted your PC. The symptoms you described are identical to my problem with losing Polish diacritical characters when I have an active RDP session open in background.
Did you try to replace the keyboard?

Comment: Another try: do you use VirtualBox? If yes, then read here: http://blog.oliver-mueller.com/-102

Comment: @MBu I don't use VirtualBox. I've tried multiple USB keyboards to eliminate mechanical failure. I've also tried to remove keyboard from device manager and reboot. No success. Tried to reinstall graphics driver (NVIDIA GTX 650M) - nothing. Tried common shortcuts to change keyboard layout like lCrtl + lShift, Shift + Shift and WindowsKeys + Space - nothing helped. I'm currently gathering install files since OS reinstall seems inevitable... damn...

Comment: Same problem here. Win 8.1 home.
They stoped working today. rCTRL+rALT works fine.
I think this is windows update related.

Comment: I've confirmed with Samsung support that this is Windows Update related. I've started with a clean Win 8.1 Enterprise installation and tried to figure out which of the updates makes this happen. After about 140 I've gave up...

Comment: It still is. I've started with a clean system installation and after updates it still occures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK! After two days of struggle I've managed to reclaim my diacritics :)

The reason for this issue is: Synaptics device driver! To remove the issue simply go to Control Panel > Add or remove programs > Remove Synaptics.

After that go to Windows Update, search for new updates and this will try to install the driver again. Instead of installing the update - HIDE it. After security prompt the driver will appear grey'd out and the issue is solved :)

[image: Driver in Windows Update]

Information confirmed with Microsoft Support.

Comment: any chance to get multi-touch scroll again?

Comment: I've investigated the issue further and I've learned that the issue is exactly when you update the update service installs the pre-windows 8 driver. Try to install the newest driver but forbid it to update. Maybe this will help.