# Windows keyboard change doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop, but suddenly my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> button doesn't want to work anymore...

So now I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to perform actions.

I hate this because I'm a developer that writes a lot of characters like `{`, `}`, `#`, `@`, `|`, etc... Now, I tried to make my own keyboard layout via Microsoft keyboard layout generator 4.1 I save my work, but when I verifier, it gives some warnings...

This is the log:

```
WARNING: { (U+007b) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_9, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt' and VK_4, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: ~ (U+007e) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_OEM_PLUS, ShiftState 'Shift+Ctl+Alt' and VK_OEM_PLUS, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: ´ (U+00b4) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_OEM_3, ShiftState 'Shift+Ctl+Alt' and VK_OEM_3, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: ` (U+0060) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_OEM_5, ShiftState 'Shift+Ctl+Alt' and VK_OEM_5, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: ^ (U+005e) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_OEM_6, ShiftState 'Base' and VK_6, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: [ (U+005b) is already defined more than once on the keyboard (on VK_OEM_6, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt' and VK_5, ShiftState 'Ctl+Alt').
    WARNING: '<' defined on OEM_102 (Base) but not defined elsewhere. This key may not be present on all keyboards.
    WARNING: '>' defined on OEM_102 (Shift) but not defined elsewhere. This key may not be present on all keyboards.
    WARNING: '\' defined on OEM_102 (Ctl+Alt) but not defined elsewhere. This key may not be present on all keyboards.
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'à' and '0' (VK_0, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '&' and '1' (VK_1, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'é' and '2' (VK_2, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '"' and '3' (VK_3, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between ''' and '4' (VK_4, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '(' and '5' (VK_5, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '§' and '6' (VK_6, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'è' and '7' (VK_7, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '!' and '8' (VK_8, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'ç' and '9' (VK_9, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '$' and '*' (VK_OEM_1, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '=' and '+' (VK_OEM_PLUS, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between ',' and '?' (VK_OEM_COMMA, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '-' and '_' (VK_OEM_MINUS, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between ';' and '.' (VK_OEM_PERIOD, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between ':' and '/' (VK_OEM_2, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'ù' and '%' (VK_OEM_3, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between ')' and '°' (VK_OEM_4, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between 'µ' and '£' (VK_OEM_5, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
    WARNING: Caps Lock is set between '^' and '¨' (VK_OEM_6, ShiftStates 'Base' and 'Shift').
```

Now, it works (my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) when I test it in that program, but when I install it, it doesn't...

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I really want to have this fixed, and I don't know how it could have happened that my button stopped working....

### edit

When I try to do `Alt Gr` `+` `@/2/é` << that button...
inside of Skype, it seems to have another function... weird..

Comment: Have you accidentally switched to a different IME? I have three installed and I accidentally hit the keycombination to swap (LtShift + Alt) more often than I expect.

Comment: I only have 1 keyboard (also 1 IME I guess)... I can't swich between 2 different keyboards.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, no ideas alas from this side. I'll see if I can scrounge a keyboard with an alt-gr key tomorrow at the office and try replicate the error.

Comment: I have a azerty keyboard, a dutch one...

Comment: It seems to be a broken update. Possible duplicates [Windows 8.1 Alt Gr, win key](http://superuser.com/q/929264) and [Polish diacritical signs not working](http://superuser.com/q/928555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's propable because of the automatic update of the Synaptics pointing device. Just right click on My Computer' then select 'Manage' then select 'Device manager' then open 'Mice or other pointing devices'. If the Synaptics device exists then double click on it then select driver tab and push 'revert'.

I have a Samsung notebook with exactly the same situation here.

At the end you have to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe not the best answer, take it as a workaround:*

Install open-source tool [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) and [remap the keys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) that way. It can help you at least temporarily.

Do not forget that the tool has to be running with administrator privileges. Without them, it sometimes doesn't work reliably.