# Windows 8.1 Alt Gr, win key

Tags: windows-8.1

Recently I got an automatic windows update and it seems it has "bugged" some things out. For example my AltGr (right alt) is not working anymore as it should and when I hold the windows key down it's constatly flashing through metro and desktop, which is preventing some win key shortcuts from not working, eg. win+s, win+r, win+d, ...

Comment: Probably same issue as here: [Polish diacritical signs not working](http://superuser.com/q/928555/194694)

Comment: It seems that the microsoft updates are the problem, I have a Samsung laptop aswell and use no virtual machines. I guess we'll have to wait for the fix.
Thanks for that link.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt should be the same as AltGr.

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to correct the problem and now things work as it should. I payed close attention to this post [Polish diacritical signs not working](https://superuser.com/questions/928555/polish-diacritical-signs-not-working). It seems that the new Synaptics drivers update is the root of this problem.