# Alt + key not working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Since yesterday, my keyboard has been working differently. Here a few problems:

- The <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>another key</kbd> shortcuts works, but the desktop always switches to the start screen.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> shortcus works adding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>=> "@", instead of only <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>). Although, the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut navigation is working

I tried to change the keyboard and check if it was a RPD issue, nothing worked. What can I do?

Comment: A related issue is solved here, hopefully it helps:

http://superuser.com/questions/928555/issues-with-win-key-and-right-alt-key-after-windows-update-polish-diacritical-s

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the keyboard layout through "windows key"+"Space".

Switching the layout by means of Alt + Shift did not help before. A reboot also fixes it.