# Windows 8.1 hotkeys got screwed

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

After an upgrade which happened in last couple of weeks my Windows 8.1 got strange behavior in regards to user-input.

1. All hotkeys like `Win + D`, `Win + R`, `Win + Q` and so on, result in opening Metro interface (or however it is called at the moment) besides of the desired action. Pressing `Win + E` results in opening new file-explorer window **AND** opening and Metro interface.
2. Layout switching hot keys, i.e. `Alt + Shift`, I have three language layouts setup and I can not use `Alt + Shift` any longer. I went to language settings and changed my shortcut to `Ctrl + Shift`, which partially works. If I switch setting back to `Alt + Shift` - nothing works. By partially I mean that shortcut doesn't work on logon screen, where it used to work without an issue. So, at the moment I have to use language bar to switch my languages with mouse in many cases.

I tried googling several times for these issues and found nothing relevant. My colleagues also doesn't seem to have that issue on their computers, though they upgraded as well.

Update
My computer is Samsung NP550P5C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polish diacritical signs not working (issues with win key and right alt key)](http://superuser.com/questions/928555/polish-diacritical-signs-not-working-issues-with-win-key-and-right-alt-key)

Comment: this is a duplicate indeed, issue solved

Comment: great. You should be able to close it as a duplicate yourself (by clicking the "That solved my problem button!"

Comment: I don't see `close` button, maybe not enough reputation

Comment: See [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981) for what you should see ...

Comment: don't see it, maybe because I added a little update to the question description

Comment: Well, actually I will update my question with sort of related thing.

Comment: Never mind, it will eventually get closed as a dup anyway by the normal procedure. **Please ask a new question if you want to ask something related**. You can always link back to this question for context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's caused by one or more desktop applications that install [Win 8 incompatible] shell extensions into the Windows right-click context menu.

Download and run http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html from Nir Sofer's brilliant site. This util lists every shell extension and allows you to quickly disable them.

With offending shell extension disabled , every option on the 8.1 Power Users (Win + X) menu will work.